# Preload/Cache MP4 data in Flash, to play at later point

Tags: flash, apache-flex, caching, video, mp4

I'm hoping someone can help, I can find a million pages peripheral to this issue but none that actually seem to relate directly!

I need to load mp4 files into a Flash/Flex application, and these need to be preloaded and cached, in the same manner that one can BitmapData or Sound objects - however, the Video class is a display object and NetStream/Connection seem tailored to streaming, none seem to have an API for caching and retaining mp4 video data (and from what I read, the appendBytes method doesn't work for mp4!) - the only method for loading data is `play()`, which isn't what I want to do at the point of loading...

For this reason the NetStream and NetConnection don't seem like they'd be of much use, given that they're for live streaming. Is there any way I can load mp4 binary data using a URLLoader
and attach it to a video object at a later point without having to use these classes?

Thanks in advance, I am going a bit mad over this!

Comment: I have to **strongly recommend** against doing this. The caching you refer to is saving the video to memory. Videos get very large (for example, a 720x480, 3 minute video I have for an app is 100MB) and you really should not be saving these types of things to memory. In short, you run the risk of running out of RAM. Now, if you are using Adobe AIR, you could save the video to disk. But you don't want to do this without user-permission (again, using up a lot of disk space is generally not good)

Comment: the videos will never be hi-res or long, never more than a few Mb each, and there will never be more than six at a time. However, when I need to trigger them I do need them to trigger instantly, and to be scrubbable without delays, so I do need to do it this way.

Comment: Well, then the route to go would be to download the file using `URLLoader`, save the data into a `ByteArray` that you save somewhere, likely with a static variable so it doesn't get garbage collected. Then you use `appendBytes()`. According tot he documentation, it should work on h.264 on all platforms except iOS. If this is for iOS, I think you may be out of luck and have to resort to streaming.

Comment: I've not tried this yet but seen a couple of comments which state that this isn't possible with MP4 data...do you know if this pertains only to iOS? I'll try and set up a test case tonight in any case...

Comment: [`NetStream#appendBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes()). "Note: This method is not supported for H.264 video in AIR 3.0 for iOS."